# parallelograms formed by horizontal and vertical lines

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me with this problem or give me an hint on how to solve it? I don't think I do not understand this problem well. How can two horizontal and vertical lines create 360 parallelograms?

> In a plane, there are n parallel horizontal lines and 9 parallel vertical lines. If there are 360 possible parallelograms that can be formed by using 2 horizontal lines and two vertical lines, what is n?

Answer (score 2):

There are not two horizontal and vertical lines - there are $9$ parallel vertical lines and $n$ parallel horizontal lines. As they are parallel, all that is needed to create a parallelogram is to choose any two vertical and any two horizontal lines. The number of parallelograms that can be formed is thus given by the number of ways to make this choice.

Two horizontal lines can be chosen in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways. Two vertical lines can be chosen in $\binom{9}2$ ways. The choice of each is independent. Thus, we have

$$\text{Number of parallelograms}=360=\binom{n}{2}\times\binom{9}{2}$$
$$360=\binom{n}{2}\times36$$
$$\binom{n}{2}=10$$
$$n=5$$